# Using VBScript to find most recent file date in a single folder

Tags: file-io, vbscript, wsh

How could I modify this VBScript to return only the newest file's name and Last Modified date?  Currently it returns anything modified in the last 24 hours.  I want to look for the most recent file only.  I borrowed this from StackOverflow, not yet a VBScript wizard.

```
option explicit  
dim fileSystem, folder, file
dim path   
path = "C:\test"  
Set fileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set folder = fileSystem.GetFolder(path) 
for each file in folder.Files         
if file.DateLastModified > dateadd("h", -24, Now) then         
'whatever you want to do to process'         
WScript.Echo file.Name & " last modified at " & file.DateLastModified     
end if
next
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For working with files on `VBScript` it is recommended you use the `FileSystemObject`.

The `FileSystemObject` has the following feature's that help you solve your problem:

- `FileSystemObject.GetFolder` - Returns a Folder object corresponding to the folder in a specified path.
- `Folder.Files` - Returns a Files collection consisting of all File objects contained in the specified folder.
- `File.DateLastModified` - Returns the date and time that the specified file or folder was last modified.

To demonstrate, I have supplied an implementation of `GetRecentFile` (and `GetRecentFolder`) which scans the supplied input path and determines the most recent file by finding the file that has the greatest `DateLastModified` property.

```
Option Explicit  

Function GetRecentFile(path)
  Dim fso, file
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set GetRecentFile = Nothing
  For Each file in fso.GetFolder(path).Files
    If GetRecentFile is Nothing Then
      Set GetRecentFile = file
    ElseIf file.DateLastModified > GetRecentFile.DateLastModified Then
      Set GetRecentFile = file
    End If
  Next
End Function

Function GetRecentFolder(path)
  Dim fso, folder
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set GetRecentFolder = Nothing
  For Each folder in fso.GetFolder(path).SubFolders
    If GetRecentFolder is Nothing Then
      Set GetRecentFolder = folder
    ElseIf folder.DateLastModified > GetRecentFolder.DateLastModified Then
      Set GetRecentFolder = folder
    End If
  Next
End Function

Dim recentFile
Set recentFile = GetRecentFolder("C:\Temp")
If recentFile is Nothing Then
  WScript.Echo "No recent files found"
Else
  WScript.Echo "Recent file is " & recentFile.Name & " " & recentFile.DateLastModified
End If
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getfolder-method
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/files-property
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datelastmodified-property

Comment: Works for finding recent folders too.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me! A very much broken down version of previous answer.

```
Set GetRecentFile = Nothing
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If GetRecentFile is Nothing then
        Set GetRecentFile = objFile
    ElseIf objFile.DateLastModified > GetRecentFile.DateLastModified then
        Set GetRecentFile = objFile
    End If
Next
```